# Bootstrap collapse not working for content loaded via Ajax

Tags: ajax, twitter-bootstrap

I am new to Bootstrap. I am facing a problem which I am not able to figure out the reason. If I load a content dynamically the `collapse` is not working. It is not adding the class `in` on hover as in http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#collapse but if the same `html` copied from dom and added as a static element the method is working. I am using `ajax` to load the content and in the `complete` function initializing the events. Any idea why the content don't expand on hover with `ajax`.

Comment: I have the same issue. It has to do with jQuery not picking up DOM changes. I am looking for a solution too.

Comment: I get the exact same issue after content loaded by ajax. It affects the accordion too. All the solutions with calling "$(".collapse").collapse(); after contents are loaded dynamically" completely miss the point! What we want is  a way to reattach the data-toggle attribute based events after the ajax call

Answer (score 0):

Call `$(".collapse").collapse();` after contents are loaded dynamically.

Comment: If you do that, an entire document/page will expand collapsed elements.